# Why should I use debug.keystore when generate facebook hash key for android?

Tags: android, facebook, keystore

I have seen some examples that use ~/.android/debug.keystore for generating the facebook hash key for android. Is this correct? Or should I use the keystore that I use to sign my apk?

Answer (score 0):

Please use the keystore that you use to sign my apk

Thank you.